# Wordpress версии 3.3.1 и PHP 5.4 не работает админка

Tags: php, wordpress

В версии PHP 5.3 сайт и админка нормально работает.
На хостинге установлен PHP 5.4 и там, сам сайт работает а в админке видно только панель слева, а справа чистый лист.
Можно ли как то исправить ситуацию не обновляя Wordpress?
И не откатывая естественно версию PHP.

Comment: 100% проблема не в версии php. включите дебаг в wp-config.php и посмотрите что он говорит

Comment: на локалке поменял версию php и заработало... уверены что не в версии php?

Comment: кроме 5 нотисов на мой взгляд безобидных ничего нету.

Comment: Пробуйте отключать плагины. Возможно, один из них использует устаревшие функции, которые были удалены в PHP 5.4.

Comment: уже пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: Вот http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.incompatible.php Обратно несовместимые изменения при переходе с 5.3 на 5.4. Может поможет.